# A tool to compare if two directory is the same?

Tags: file-transfer

I copied bulk amount of datas between computers. Can anybody tell me a tool that could compare if the contents are the same? (same amount of files, directories, file crc checks)

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of question is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Please do a bit of searching; there are many tools for this out there, depending on the operating system you use.

Answer (score 1):

You have site on Stack Exchange network for [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

You have many [tools that can help you](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-for-getting-rid-of-duplicate-files/):

1. WinMerge
2. DoubleKiller
3. Easy Duplicate Finder
4. dupeGuru Music Edition
5. Duplicate Images Finder

Comment: Seconded WinMerge. Using it myself.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not a tool to check difference betweem folders (not possible) but to *recursively* check for differences in folders.
Because when you search for such you will find many amswers on how this is possible ;-)

On Linuxes you xan do this with rsync or diff quite easily, iirc.